# How revise this code from non-redux to redux/ redux toolkit approach?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am kind of novice in react redux toolkit.

In my react project, the state management is using non-redux approach.

**I would like to look for a redux toolkit adjustment**

In BigForm, there are two state, DataA and DataB, which would be passed into FormA and FormB.

The problem is whenever I add input value into Form A or Form B, it will also trigger unnecessary render on the other components. I heard redux may help, but I am not sure how to put this in work in this example? Hope to see a revise on redux approach

The Big form components will eventually has a button on it to aggregate all the data. Let say it will make a api call that's based on the data from Form A,B,C,D,E,F

Unfortunately, in my real example, FormA and FormB are huge, and I also have other Form , like Form A,B,C too.So **.Memo and having own state in child is not effective**

That's why I am looking for redux

Here is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const FormA = (props) => {

  useEffect(()=>{ console.log('Form A was just rendered')})
  const { dataA, setDataA } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setDataA(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>Input Form A{dataA}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormB = (props) => {
  const { dataB, setDataB } = props;
  useEffect(()=>{ console.log('Form B was just rendered')})
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setDataB(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>Input Form B{dataB}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export function BigForm (props) {

  const [dataA,setDataA] = useState()
  const [dataB,setDataB] = useState()
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <FormA dataA={dataA} setDataA={setDataA}></FormA>

     <FormB dataB={dataB} setDataB={setDataB}></FormB>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard **Redux** approach with selectors based on [**Reselect**](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) . Your forms should receive data from the general Redux store through selectors that will check whether the state passed to the component has been updated.

The easiest way is to use [**Redux-toolkit**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started), it already includes memoization, selectors and Reselect by default.

Comment: Thanks man, is it possible to see your code ? I am not competent to structure it